# Block Comment Being Closed By "*/" In String

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments, block-comments

This is a quality of life question that might be awfully simple, but, I cannot seem to find an answer for it.

If you start a block comment...

```
/*
my code here
string url = "lorumipsum....*/...lorumipsum"; <---this "*/" is closing the comment early
more code
*/
```

It gets closed by any "*/" in a string. Is there a way to escape this? Or do I just manually "//" the line and block comment the rest?

Comment: You can select all text and comment from top in the toolbar. It will add // in front of all selected lines.

Comment: As I don't know a way around this, this is the reason I never found multiline-comments that useful...

Comment: The reason is obvious: what is inside comment is not *parsed* and thus it can't detect whenever `*/` is inside string or not. It just looking for `/* .... */` and completely ignores anything inside. Ignoring what is commented make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select all text and comment from toolbar (Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>). It will add `//` in front of all selected lines like this.

```
///*
//my code here
//string url = "lorumipsum....*/...lorumipsum"; <---this "*/" is closing the         comment early
//more code
//*/
```

No need to do this manually.

**Toolbar Image**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Or, you can just hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-key, click and draw across all lines that you would like to comment out and then just type `//` before them as you are in Multiline-Editmode.

Comment: Haha, that's brilliant, never knew VS has this feature.

Comment: Since I found out, I find it more useful than the compiler. ;-)